# PostgreSQL GIN pg_trgm default operator class

Tags: postgresql, index

I am using GIN indexes with the `pg_trgm` module for indexing `varchar` fields.  So, to define an index I have to write something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX gin_field_idx ON table_name USING gin (field gin_trgm_ops);
```

If I exclude the operator class (`git_trgm_ops`) and write:

```
CREATE INDEX gin_field_idx ON table_name USING gin (field);
```

PostgreSQL will raise an error:

> **ERROR:**  data type character varying has no default operator class for
>   access method "gin"
>   **HINT:**  You must specify an operator class for the
>   index or define a default operator class for the data type.

How do I define a default operator method from the module?

[This](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createopclass.html) does not help. It describes how to define a new operator class from extension operators and functions. But I have to define the default operator class from a [module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgtrgm.html).

Any help will be appreciated :-).

Comment: So you basically want to roll your own version of `pg_trgm` in order to save a few characters when creating indexes?

Comment: @dezso No. It is necessary for greater good. I am adding `pg_trgm` to database of large Ruby on Rails(RoR) project. RoR have two ways of migrating database: 1 - by `rake db:migrate` or 2 - by loading `schema.rb`. In both cases it breaks older migrations indexes, those already has GIN index type, because they do not have described class. So i want to add default class for not to break older migrations.

Comment: If RoR doesn't do this migration properly, wouldn't it be better to fix RoR so that it does work properly, rather than changing pg_trgm in some customized way?  Is your plan to make and maintain your own fork of pg_trgm?

Comment: I get this error even when I use `gin("somecol", gin_trgm_ops)`. And I have the extension created too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can update the pg_opclass table and set the default.

```
update pg_opclass set opcdefault = true where opcname='gin_trgm_ops'
```

pg_trgm doesn't do this by default as you might have/want a different GIN default.

```
select * from pg_opclass where opcname = 'gin_trgm_ops';
```

than you can create an index:

```
create index ON table USING gin (field); -- it will use the new default
```

Comment: Let me add a small advisory: manually changing the system catalog may result in unexpected behaviour.  This solution works until there is no conflict on the default operator class: if another extension would have its set to default for type `text`, this change would cause a conflict.

Comment: This works immediately, but is pretty dreadful.  You are almost guaranteeing yourself problems when it comes to upgrading your database or merging two databases together into one, or splitting one apart.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a preference to what is the default behavior, it's up to the DBA to make sure which opclass is default. As with any upgrade/migration the DBA will need to make sure that this setting persists.

Comment: @cohenjo Sure the DBA can micromanage the database, but isn't that directly at odds with what RoR is intended for?

Comment: It's a simple update to run with the extension creation, it's a small price to pay :)

Comment: @jjanes The project is rather static. What do you mean when you say that i'am guarantee problems during migration of update. You re talking about adding new table or updating postgres version?

Comment: Upgrading postgres versions.  Fortunately I think the problem is only with major version upgrades, not minor version upgrades.

Comment: @jjanes I have been asked for developer. He said that there will be only two probably occasions: 1 -> If other extension will try to set default op class (more possible), then there will be error during adding extension. 2 -> If there will be default op class in postgres core (nearly impossible in near future) then pg_update will fail.